# Postfix : restricting specific domain for specific user

Tags: linux, postfix-mta, mail-server

I am new to postfix . How can I blacklist specific domain for specific user using restriction class or by some other method.

Suppose my machine has two users - `user1` and `user2`.

I want to blacklist or block the mails from `abc.com` to `user1@mydomain` whereas `user2@mydomain.com` can receive.

Similarly `xyz.com` should be blocked for `user2@mydomain.com` whereas `user1@mydomain.com` can receive.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use restrictions class.

In `main.cf`, define your class like this:

> smtpd_restriction_classes = ... ban_abc_com
>
> ban_abc_com = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/ban_adc_com, permit

The `ban_adc_com` file will contain:

> adc.com REJECT

Then create a file table named `protected_destinations` containing:

> user1@mydomain ban_abc_com

Then link all together in `main.cf`:

> smtpd_recipient_restrictions = ..., check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/protected_destinations

For user2, create a new class similar to ban_adc_com, then add in `protected_destinations` a new line containing:

> user2@mydomain ban_xyz_com

You can see more here: [Postfix restriction classes](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html#internal)